How to manage Users that login with OAuth2 with Spring Boot
So, I'm trying to learn OAuth2 social login and I'm having problems to understand how i should manage those users that logged with Auth2. Should I create a Resource Server that manages it or other class? How can i implement it? It's hard to find something like that on internet, all tutorials i checked just teach how to implement the basic ideia of login, not the post login management. Could you help me, please?
What I mean with management is how I integrate the user with DB? How to control the access his access to each end point? Don't need to show me code just a ideia of what to do.
I just want to understand the concept, apply is not a problem, i just feel kinda lost and don't know if what i am doing is right.

what exactly do you mean by manage ? What operations are you thinking about ?

Hi, you are asking how to manage the authorization phase, that comes after the authorization, that if I understand correctly is done through social login (ie. FB or others, right?). I have experience in a similar scenario, tell me if this is the case and I'll try to write a summary to explain the architecture that we implemented.

OAuth2 actors responsibilities:

authorization servers:

user authentication
user management (roles and details)
client management


clients:

getting tokens from the authorization server: drive an OAuth2 flows (like authorization code and refresh token as configured by oauth2Login)
authorizing requests to resource servers: setting the Authorization header with a Bearer token


resource servers:

validating access tokens (with a JWT decoder or by introspecting it on the authorization server)
taking access control decisions



Access control implementation on resource servers
Using Spring Security and method security expressions, you can implement (and unit test) about any access control rule.
Picking an authorization Server
Using "social" identity providers directly is OK solely when working with a monolithic app with oauth2Login and when user management is not a requirement:

These OPs generally issue opaque tokens with their own APIs as audience. So we can't efficiently use access tokens to authorize requests to our resource servers.
What we can read & update about the user depends on the scope he grants to our client, and will usually not include things like roles for our system.

As a consequence, when the app contains microservices configured as resource servers, or when we want to manage user data, then we need an OP of our own as a facade for one or more of these "Social" providers.
Keycloak is a common choice with built-in social login among many features like multi-factor authentication, email verification, protection against brute force attacks, UI for user profiles edition, rather easy style customization, REST API to manipulate about everything, and more. See this article I just updated to get started with Keycloak and Spring.
You can also look at cloud offers like Auth0, Amazon Cognito, etc.
If you prefer a "do it yourself", there is Spring Authorization Server project. But considering the effort to implement the features listed above and your knowledge of the OAuth2 & OpenID standards, I strongly advise you pick something "off the shelf"...

@wesley-rabelo would you please detail what is unclear or why this doesn't answer your question?

How does one do full session deletion from Redis and Auth0 RP Initiated logout when a BFF session naturally expires (rather than hitting explicit /logout endpoint)  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/3190, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78959714/spinning-up-spring-instances-how-to-prevent-redis-cache-overload and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78959874/spring-security-how-to-delete-sessions-from-redis-and-do-auth0-logout-when-s
