Spinning up Spring Instances - how to prevent Redis Cache Overload
My Spring BFF has a function designed to clean up sessions in Redis, periodically, every 2 minutes using the 'Scheduled' annotation.
One issue I've read is that if I put this in a Docker container and spin up multiple instances of the container, then this function will run in every container, which is not really necessary. Is there some kind of mechanism I can use to prevent this from happening. E.g. what is a distribution lock? Would that be useful?
Spring Redis Cache Session Clean Up function
/**
 * For cleanup operations (i.e. removing expired session from a ZSet (Sorted Sets) in Redis)
 * Spring's scheduling mechanism will automatically call the cleanup method according to the schedule
 * defined by the @Scheduled annotation.
 */
@Component
@EnableScheduling
internal class SessionEvicter(
    private val redisOperations: ReactiveRedisOperations<String, String>,
    springSessionProperties: SpringSessionProperties,
) {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionEvicter::class.java)

    private val redisKeyLocation = springSessionProperties.redis?.expiredSessionsNamespace
        ?: "spring:session:sessions:expirations"

    data class CleanupContext(
        val now: Instant,
        val pastFiveDays: Instant,
        val range: Range<Double>,
        val limit: Limit
    )

    // run every 120 seconds
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 120, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    fun cleanup(): Mono<Void> {
        return Mono.fromCallable {
            val now = Instant.now()
            val pastFiveDays = now.minus(Duration.ofDays(5))
            val range = Range.closed(
                pastFiveDays.toEpochMilli().toDouble(),
                now.toEpochMilli().toDouble()
            )
            val limit = Limit.limit().count(500)
            CleanupContext(now, pastFiveDays, range, limit)
        }
        .doOnNext { context ->
            logger.info("Scheduled cleanup execution started at ${Instant.now()}.")
            logger.info("Current time (now): ${context.now}")
            logger.info("Time range start: ${Date(context.pastFiveDays.toEpochMilli())}")
            logger.info("Time range end: ${Date(context.now.toEpochMilli())}")
            logger.info("Limit count: ${context.limit.count}")
            logger.info("Redis key location: $redisKeyLocation")
        }
        .flatMap { context ->
            val zSetOps = redisOperations.opsForZSet()
            zSetOps.reverseRangeByScore(redisKeyLocation, context.range, context.limit)
                .collectList()
                .flatMap { sessionIdsList ->
                    if (sessionIdsList.isNotEmpty()) {
                        logger.info("Found ${sessionIdsList.size} sessions to remove.")
                        zSetOps.remove(
                            redisKeyLocation,
                            *sessionIdsList.toTypedArray()
                        ).doOnSubscribe { logger.info("Started removal of sessions") }
                            .doOnSuccess { logger.info("Successfully removed sessions") }
                            .doOnError { e -> logger.error("Error during removal: ${e.message}") }
                    } else {
                        logger.info("No sessions found to remove.")
                        Mono.empty()
                    }
                }
        }
        .doOnSuccess {
            logger.info("Scheduled session cleanup check completed at ${Instant.now()}.")
        }
        .doOnError { e ->
            logger.error("Error during session cleanup check: ${e.message}")
        }
        .then()
        .doOnTerminate {
            logger.info("Cleanup process terminated at ${Instant.now()}.")
        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()) // to ensure proper threading
    }


}

