Spring Security - how to delete sessions from Redis, and do Auth0 logout, when BFF session naturally expires
My Spring BFF sort of almost works.
The issue I am encountering relates to the fact that while Spring Session / Security is saving my session data to Redis and applying a TTL (Time-To-Live) to the main session keys, the associated indexed keys (such as attributes indexed for lookups) are not automatically being set with a TTL. This means that these indexed keys can persist indefinitely unless manually deleted (e.g., through an explicit logout), leading to a potential memory leak.
Explicit Logout
When I explicity logout, the following function gets called, and so the session is deleted from (i) namespace > sessions, (ii) namespace > sessions > expires, (iii) namespace > sessions > session id > idx, (iv) and namespace > sessions > expiration (sorted set)
https://github.com/dreamstar-enterprises/docs/blob/master/Spring%20BFF/BFF/src/main/kotlin/com/frontiers/bff/auth/handlers/SessionServerLogoutHandler.kt#L40
Which calls this and this:
https://github.com/dreamstar-enterprises/docs/blob/master/Spring%20BFF/BFF/src/main/kotlin/com/frontiers/bff/auth/handlers/SessionServerLogoutHandler.kt#L40
https://github.com/dreamstar-enterprises/docs/blob/master/Spring%20BFF/BFF/src/main/kotlin/com/frontiers/bff/auth/sessions/SessionControl.kt#L53
Which calls this and this:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/main/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/server/session/SpringSessionWebSessionStore.java#L162
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/main/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/server/session/SpringSessionWebSessionStore.java#L100
Which both ultimately call this:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/main/spring-session-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/ReactiveRedisIndexedSessionRepository.java#L387
The 4 delete methods in here get called
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/main/spring-session-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/ReactiveRedisIndexedSessionRepository.java#L391
The following also gets called to do an RP Initiated Logout (to end the session that exists with the Auth0 Authorization server too)

the delete BFF session, delete 2 cookies here:

https://github.com/dreamstar-enterprises/docs/blob/master/Spring%20BFF/BFF/src/main/kotlin/com/frontiers/bff/auth/handlers/SessionServerLogoutHandler.kt

the logout from the auth server here (RP Initiated Logout):

https://github.com/dreamstar-enterprises/docs/blob/master/Spring%20BFF/BFF/src/main/kotlin/com/frontiers/bff/auth/handlers/oauth2/OAuth2ServerLogoutSuccessHandler.kt
Natural BFF session expiration
But how do I do the above, when the BFF session reaches its natural expiration time.
When this happens Redis still leaves the following

Also the Auth0 session is never logged out from (so if the person logs in again via the Spring BFF, and the Auth0 session is still valid, then it will silently login without showing the Auth0 login page)
